# Check FileName From HttpHostedFileBase is File Name or File Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-upload

I am developing an application which store filename in database. For Mozilla & Chrome it is showing FileName only but in IE it is showing full path of file. Now I want to check whether given filename is filename or filepath. Is there any way to do it?

**Here is my code:**

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> attachments)
{
  byte[] image = null;
  var file = attachments.First();
  // Some browsers send file names with full path. We only care about the file name.
  string filePath = Server.MapPath(General.FaxFolder + "/" + file.FileName);
  file.SaveAs(filePath);
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
  {
    image = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
  }
  TempData["Image"] = image;
  System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);            
  return Json(new { status = "OK", imageString = Convert.ToBase64String(image) }, "text/plain");
}
```

Comment: Instead of check whether the file has a path or not, what you can do is to just use `GetFileName(path);` method

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee, thanks that's work for all browser.

Comment: you can make the same edit to the question, so that It will help somebody else.

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee, well ur ans is same as just code and it helped so +1

Comment: well actually I already answered the same in the comment :)

Comment: next time I'll keep this in my mind :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well,If you go with getting filename only in any browser then you should write

```
Path.GetFileName(e.fileName);
```

It will return filename only in any browser 
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, This is the simplest way to get file name.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of check whether the file has a path or not, what you can do is to just use 
`GetFileName(path);`method